# Why model binding with a struct doesn't work?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to understand why this binding doesn't work.
The binding didn't work until I changed the type from `struct` to `class`.
Is this by design or am I missing something?

I'm using asp.net core 2.2 MVC

**View Models**

*Not working*

```
public class SettingsUpdateModel
{
    public DeviceSettingsStruct DeviceSettings  { get; set; }
}
```

*Working*

```
public class SettingsUpdateModel
{
    public DeviceSettingsClass DeviceSettings  { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class DeviceSettingsClass
{
    public bool OutOfScheduleAlert { get; set; }
// other fields removed for brevity
}

public struct DeviceSettingsStruct
{
    public bool OutOfScheduleAlert { get; set; }
// other fields removed for brevity
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Update(SettingsUpdateModel newSettings)
{
    // newSettings.DeviceSettings.OutOfScheduleAlert always false on struct but correct on class
    return Index(null);
}
```

**View**

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="out_of_schedule_checkbox" asp-for="DeviceSettings.OutOfScheduleAlert">
```

Expected: `DeviceSettings.OutOfScheduleAlert` to bind to a struct the same as class
Actual: only the class parameter was binded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design in complex type model bindings. A [struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/struct) type is a value type that is typically used to encapsulate small groups of related variables, such as the coordinates of a rectangle or the characteristics of an item in an inventory.

In ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs , the `CanUpdateReadOnlyProperty` method will mark the properties of `value-type` model as readonly due to value types have copy-by-value semantics, which prevents us from updating

```
internal static bool CanUpdatePropertyInternal(ModelMetadata propertyMetadata)
    {
        return !propertyMetadata.IsReadOnly || CanUpdateReadOnlyProperty(propertyMetadata.ModelType);
    }

    private static bool CanUpdateReadOnlyProperty(Type propertyType)
    {
        // Value types have copy-by-value semantics, which prevents us from updating
        // properties that are marked readonly.
        if (propertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Arrays are strange beasts since their contents are mutable but their sizes aren't.
        // Therefore we shouldn't even try to update these. Further reading:
        // http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/22/arrays-considered-somewhat-harmful.aspx
        if (propertyType.IsArray)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Special-case known immutable reference types
        if (propertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Reference [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ModelBinding/Binders/ComplexTypeModelBinder.cs) for more details .

BTY ,if you want to bind struct type model , you could try to send the json data by using ajax request from the view.